# How might I detect serif and sans-serif fonts in Python/OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to create a Python program that prints the names of the fonts installed on my computer and also prints whether each font is a serif font or sans-serif font (I don't want to manually type up whether a font is serif or not). I've gotten my program to print a list of the names of the fonts installed on my computer, but I have no idea how to make a program that detects whether a font is a serif or sans-serif font.

Right now I am thinking of creating images with the alphabet in the given font and comparing it to the alphabet in Times New Roman (since Times New Roman is a fairly standard serif font), which is why I'm thinking of using OpenCV. Alternatively, I might write a program to look for angles/curves in each letter to identify where the serifs are, which might be better but might also require writing a different program for each letter.

However, these are just ideas and I have no idea how I could actually go about implementing this. Does anyone have any suggestions for a package or module I could look into?

Edited for clarity, hopefully this is more understandable

Comment: How would you *define* the difference between serif and sans-serif fonts?

Comment: @Scott Hunter I would say when the character has protrusions at its ends. If there is any uncertainty in my program, I would likely go with sans-serif over serif. Handwritten fonts and cursive fonts would also end up going into the sans-serif bin in this case.

Comment: I am also thinking of just comparing every font to Times New Roman and seeing if the images line up roughly, or doing a letter by letter analysis of the protrusions of the character (for example, for the character A, looking for serifs at either leg, then for B, looking for serifs at the top and bottom left).

Comment: This confuses me, are you trying to detect font in image or font in a website? You have defined you want to do it python but not from where you get data...

Comment: @Ruli No, I'm not detecting a font in an image or a font in a website. I'm just trying to write python code that gets the fonts on your computer and tells you whether the fonts are serif or sans-serif.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to do a fairly reliable version of this!

I took all the fonts that I wanted to analyze for serif/sans-serif and printed the letter "N" in each font onto a blank png. I then ran OpenCV's [Hough Transform](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html) function on the image to identify the left side of the N and created a line on top of the left side of the N. If there were extra bits (the serifs) to the left of this line, then I said the font was a serif font. Else, I said the font was a sans-serif font.

A little crude but unexpectedly effective! The only fonts it had some trouble with were the weird Wingding and very stylized fonts.